# Transit visa in Schengen states

Tags: transit

I am travelling to the USA with KLM and my routing is as follows:

BOM - CDG - AMS - ORD.

Do I require a Schengen visa (Airport Transit etc)?

My ticket is a single ticket and all connections are within 2 hours.

Please help.

Comment: To be perfectly clear: an airport transit visa is **not sufficient** for this itinerary.

Comment: Air France (which is a partner of KLM) fly BOM-CDG-ORD; you should try to get re-routed. On the one-stop itinerary, you will _not_ need a Schengen visa assuming you have a valid USA visa (which is obvious).

Answer (score 6):

If you are a visa required national for the Schengen Area, you will need a full Schengen Visa since the flight between CDG to AMS is an intra-Schengen Area flight. You will therefore have to enter the Schengen Area in Paris to catch that flight.